# Best Flash CS5 / Actionscript 3 FLVPlayback component

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air, flvplayback

Hate to ask this question but I have been banging my head against a wall for a while now.  I have an Adobe Air 2.5 app that has been written in Flash CS5.  There is a need to play video's from within that app and I am not in the mood to write a video player from scratch.  Soooooo... we attempted to use the FLVPlayer from http://devbase.com but could not get the thing to work properly at all through their API.

The video player must go full screen and have the normal playhead scrubbing, play / pause / stop, and volume controls.

Any ideas?  Can you make the FLVPlayback control go fullscreen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One library to take a look at would the the [Open source media Framework](http://www.opensourcemediaframework.com/).  It's not a full featured player, but using it as a framework you can write your own custom skin in a day or two.  This [tutorial](http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=129) will help you get started if you are interested.

It is definitely not a complete video player solution if that what you were looking for, but if you need some level of graphical customization it would be a good option.

Comment: OSMF can be installed like a component and be controlled through actionscript?

Comment: It is installed by simply adding the .swc into the library.  It is controlled through script by creating a MediaSprite and then pointing it to a file to download an play.  The developer is still responsible for creating all the controls like play/pause/seek, but OSMF does most of the heavy lifting because you can simply call Load("video_url"); Play(), Seek(), etc...

Comment: Amazing, never used it before :)